# Why does the website heading on pubvantage.com display arbitrary text when it is listed in google search results?

Tags: html, http-headers

the website www.pubvantage.com has a permanent redirect to http://exchange.contextweb.com/sellingdesk/pubvantage/.

The problem is, when a user enters the query +"pubvantage" in google, the site (www.pubvantage.com) displays with the header text of "Ken Lauer." Ken has nothing to do with the website, and his name appears nowhere in the source code.

How can I change this?

Answer (score 2):

Allow google to index the page which pubvantage.com redirects. It's currently noindex, nofollow.

Answer (score 2):

The page you are redirected to includes this code:

```
<meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
```

This instructs the search engines not to index that page nor follow any links from it. So I recommend removing that ASAP.

Regarding the title: when I search for `+"pubvantage"` I currently see "wordpress" as the page title. Since there is no content on pubvantage.com and the contextweb.com site is not indexed, the title is probably coming from a link to pubvantage.com. If you have control over any links to the site, try changing them to "PubVantage" or whatever makes sense.

Longer term it is more beneficial to return a regular site at pubvantage.com. If you don't have your own content it is fairly straightforward to change the domain's "A NAME" to point to the other page.